# What is the syntax of a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say I have two structures,

```
struct ptr1
{
    struct ptr2 *ptrtoptr;
};

struct ptr2
{
    int name;
};
```

Main function looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    struct ptr1 *var1;
    struct ptr2 *var2;

    (code for manipulating structure element name);

    return 0;
}
```

How do a manipulate data of variable `name` via pointer `var1`? Let's say both pointers are already pointed at a certain address.

Is this correct? `var1->(var2->name)=(some value)` or `(var1->var2)->name=(some value)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do a manipulate data of variable name via pointer var1 ?

Using :

```
var1->ptrtoptr->name =  some_value ; // or (var1->ptrtoptr)->name
```

Neither of `var1->(var2->name)=(some value)` or `(var1->var2)->name=(some value)` make sense since `var2` is not a member of `ptr1`, which can't be accessed using `var1`

---

<sup>**Note:** Also, be cautions about the operator associativity , operator `->` has left to right associativity, therefore `var1->(ptroptr->value)` will not be same as `var1->ptrtoptr->name`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is very important to write functions that will help allocate and free your structures.  This will help prevent memory leaks and what not.  I wrote a sample program to show what I mean.  The other best answer accurately answers your question, I just wanted to add my two cents.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ptr1
{
    struct ptr2 *ptrtoptr;
};

struct ptr2
{
    int name;
};

struct ptr1* createPtr1() {
    struct ptr1* var1 = (struct ptr1 *) malloc(sizeof(struct ptr1));
    var1->ptrtoptr = (struct ptr2 *) malloc(sizeof(struct ptr2));

    return var1;
}

void freePtr1(struct ptr1* var1) {
    free(var1->ptrtoptr);
    free(var1);
}

int main()
{
    struct ptr1 *var1;
    struct ptr2 *var2;

    var1 = createPtr1();
    var1->ptrtoptr->name = 42;

    printf("%d\n", var1->ptrtoptr->name);
    freePtr1(var1);

    return 0;
}
```